# How to create and extend a abstract class component in VueJS?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, abstract-class

how are u doin?

So, i've been working in a new project for the company where I work.

We are going to develop a SDK to give to our third-party developers classes so they can build components to run in our application.

I want to write an **ABSTRACT CLASS** so I could force the developers to implement some methods.

How can I do this?

I was thinking about create a **PURE TYPESCRIPT CLASS** to build the **ABSTRACT CLASS** and then inherit it in my **COMPONENT CLASS**...

Something like:

```
abstract class AbstractClass {
  public abstract abstractMethod(): void
}
```

But how can I make this work with a vue component class?

Comment: See https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component . Do you have problems implementing it?

Comment: Sure! I've checked this, but I can force developers to implement some method using this? I want to use "abstract method"

Comment: Only if they use TS as well.

Comment: Now I'm using what u've sent to me! Thank you! But I am trying to implement an abstract class... When I create the mixin as it is in the guide using ABSTRACT CLASS the vue is giving me errors... :(

Comment: It would help to explain what the error is. If https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/342 is the problem, you likely won't be able to overcome this. Tbh, Vue isn't really OOP-friendly with all the magic behind its components.

Comment: Of course, you can do a check in a constructor. Since you're using TS, it would be helpful to enforce this through interfaces. I posted an example how this could be done.

Comment: Thank u man! I'll check this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`vue-class-component`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component) can be used to define Vue components as TypeScript classes but it has [a limitation](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/342) regarding abstract classes.

Depending on how abstract methods are supposed to be used, additional checks can be added to enforce their implementation in children components, e.g.:

```
interface IFooComponent {
  bar(): void;
}

@Component({})
class BaseFooComponent extends Vue {
  ['bar' as string]()  {
    throw new Error('not implemented');
  }
}

// `implements` causes compilation error
class FooComponent extends BaseFooComponent implements IFooComponent {
  // bar() {}

  mounted() {
    this.bar(); // causes both compilation and runtime error
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey man! Thank u for the help! Could u pls explain me what is this operation that u did inside the BaseFooComponent definition? I've understood u implemented a default method that throw an exception, but why did u defined it as "['bar' as string]"?

Comment: You're welcome. It's `['bar' as string]()` instead of `bar()` in order for it to be discarded by typing system, so it's not considered implemented, otherwise `this.bar()` won't cause compilation error.